# awk adding one to each number (floating or integer)

Tags: linux, awk

I want to add 1 (+1) to each number from column 2 onwards to the example file below:

```
cat example.txt

ignore the headers
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:- 76.5382 76.3422020852288
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:- 60.0702 0
```

I am trying the following command below:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[0-9]+$/) $i+=1}1' file.txt
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:- 76.5382 76.3422020852288
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:- 60.0702 1
```

My desired output should look like this below:

```
ignore the headers
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:- 77.5382 77.3422020852288
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:- 61.0702 1
```

Comment: Removing this condition should most likely work `if($i~/^[0-9]+$/)`. But do be wary of the losing of decimal digits, a `+1`, could most likely loose the original precision digits

Comment: If there's a reason why you're doing `if($i~/^[0-9]+$/)` then state what that is and included use cases in your sample input/output, otherwise just don't do that.

Comment: Sir I was using this to avoid NaN or other non-numeric values if present in my input file [if($i~/^[0-9]+$/)], I have removed it for now. Its working fine without it ! Thank you!

Comment: If you can have those in your real input then add them to your sample input.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a different condition to check numerical value:

```bash
awk -v CONVFMT=%.15g -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == $i+0) $i+=1} 1' file

chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    77.5382 77.3422020852288
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    61.0702 1
```

Here:

- `$i == $i+0` is a condition that returns `true` only when `$i` holds a numerical value
- `CONVFMT=%.15g` is used to preserve precision digits

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'if ( $. != 1 ) { @F[1, 2] = map { $_ + 1 } @F[1, 2]; } print join "\t", @F;' example.txt > output.txt
```

To change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -F'\t' -lane 'if ( $. != 1 ) { @F[1, 2] = map { $_ + 1 } @F[1, 2]; } print join "\t", @F;' example.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your original code

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[0-9]+$/) $i+=1}1' file.txt
```

is only transforming integers as your floats do contain `.` and thus do not match regular expression. You might repair that by also allowing `.` that is doing

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[.0-9]+$/) $i+=1}1' file.txt
```

observe that this will match also certain non-digits e.g. `...` or `1.2.3`, however this is problematic only if such value might appear in your file. In such case you need to refine regular expression further.